# Class incorrectly implements interface 'OnInit'. Property 'ngOnInit' is missing in type 'Component' but required in type 'OnInit'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

**Someone asked this question but not exactly the same code structure. So any help on this please?**

So here are the errors **Class 'ContactFormComponent' incorrectly implements interface 'OnInit'.
Property 'ngOnInit' is missing in type 'ContactFormComponent' but required in type 'OnInit'**

**'ngOnInit' is declared here.**

and

**Cannot find name 'ngOnInit'**

```
import { Component, Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';
import { Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'validator';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact-form',
  templateUrl: './contact-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact-form.component.scss'],
})

export class ContactFormComponent implements OnInit {

      
  checkoutForm = this.fb.group ({
    firstName :  ['', Validators.required, {updateOn: 'blur'}],
    lastName :  ['', Validators.required, {updateOn: 'blur'}],
    email :  ['', Validators.required, {updateOn: 'blur'}],
    password :  ['', Validators.required, {updateOn: 'blur'}],
    address : this.fb.group ({
      state :  ['', Validators.required, {updateOn: 'blur'}],
      country :  ['', Validators.required, {updateOn: 'blur'}],
      city :  ['', Validators.required, {updateOn: 'blur'}],
      zip :  ['', Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), Validators.maxLength(6), {updateOn: 'blur'}],
    })
  });




  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private httpService: HttpClient) { }

  get form()
  {
      return this.checkoutForm.controls;
  }

  get firstName(){
    return this.checkoutForm.get('firstName');

  }
  get lastName(){
    return this.checkoutForm.get('lastName')
  }
  get email(){
    return this.checkoutForm.get('email')
  }
  get password(){
    return this.checkoutForm.get('password')
  }
  get state(){
    return this.checkoutForm.get('state')
  }
  get country(){
    return this.checkoutForm.get('country')
  }
  get street(){
    return this.checkoutForm.get('street')
  }
  get zip(){
    return this.checkoutForm.get('zip')
  }


  onSubmit(){
    console.warn(this.checkoutForm.value)
  }

}


ngOnInit() {
  //Called after the constructor, initializing input properties, and the first call to ngOnChanges.
  //Add 'implements OnInit' to the class.

}
```

Comment: Move `ngOnInit` *inside* the ContactFormComponent component class brackets.

Comment: Yeah thanks, noticed it. New to Angular.

Answer (score 1):

Saw my error.

```
ngOnInit() {
//Called after the constructor, initializing input properties, and the first call to ngOnChanges.
  //Add 'implements OnInit' to the class.
}
```

The above code should have been in the code below

```
export class ContactFormComponent implements OnInit { }
```

for example

```
export class ContactFormComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
  //Called after the constructor, initializing input properties, and the first call to ngOnChanges.
  //Add 'implements OnInit' to the class.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add ng before OnInit() like that when u used it:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
      // console.log('hi');
    }
```